# Got an email for a filter for a question which doesn't contain any of the tags in the filter

Tags: support, subscription

I received this email yesterday:

[image]

Why?

I only have 1 filter, 'My filter', which only contains the tags [csh](/questions/tagged/csh) and [tcsh](/questions/tagged/tcsh):

[image]

As far as I can see, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536340/how-to-produce-a-sound-when-a-command-is-finished) has never been tagged with either tags (at least, they don't show up in the edit history), and the email doesn't mention them either in the tag list.

Comment: It was probably tagged `csh` or `tcsh` *anyway* but the tag was removed in a grace period edit by the OP. They used all 5 tags, my guess is that they dithered over what 5 tags to include.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's possible, but I'm not sure ...  the email doesn't show the tag, so when the system sent out the mails it knew the tags weren't on the question ... the OP also edited the question later to include [tag:fish-shell], and *seems* to know his stuff enough not to mix up completely different shells like that.